# How does assembly binding redirection work for references of references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Class Library A references `Microsoft.Data.OData` (among a number of other assemblies) and automatically rebinds references to `5.2.0.0` to the NuGet-installed `5.6.0.0` version, either through AutoUnify, or through a NuGet-provided redirection in app.config (I can't work out which applies).

Class Library B references Class Library A, but not `Microsoft.Data.OData`.

Web API Project C and Console Application D both reference Class Library B, and also specifically reference `Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.0.0`, and have app.config redirection in place.

When the solution is built in one go, all the references behave and the correct `5.6.0.0` version of the DLL is placed in the `bin` directories.

*However*, if I then debug Console Application D, some of the referenced projects are rebuilt, and (I think!) Visual Studio copies the rebuilt DLLs **and** the incorrect, `5.2.0.0` OData Dll into all of the referencing projects, including Web API Project C.

Is there any way to force VS to honour the assembly redirection to the new version when projects are individually built?

Comment: Were you able to sort this out? I'm currently battling the same issue with teamcity.

Comment: @JoseMarmolejos I was able to work around it: I added a reference to the `OData` library to each intermediate project, then ran `Add-BindingRedirect` for all projects in the NuGet package manager window. A bit brute force, but worked.